# Concatenate wav audio files leaving a small gap using SoX or other command line tool

Tags: audio, audio-conversion

I've been looking at using Sox to concatenate multiple raw audio files together.
With SoX this is as simple as

```
sox file1.wav file2.wav file3.wav out.wav
```

However I want to join the files with a small silence between each.

I could create a small silence wav and concatenate it along with the files.

```
sox file1.wav silence.wav file2.wav silence.wav file3.wav out.wav
```

I just wondered if someone knew of a more elegant solution, SoX has a ton of options but I couldn't find anything that might do this, maybe an alternative tool.

Comment: I just tried this. `sox -t sox <(sox the-proclaimers_500miles.mp3 -p pad 3 0 ) -t sox <(sox the-proclaimers_500miles.mp3 -p pad 3 0 ) -d`

Comment: very interesting, wonder how it will cope with ~150 files, I'll investigate.

Comment: Not working for me, gives `sox FAIL formats: can't open input file /dev/fd/62': premature EOF`

Comment: I get the same error, though preceded by an error saying that it can not find 500 miles by the proclaimers. It may be that you do not have this song in your present working directory.